# get some of my controllers in zend framework 2

Tags: module, zend-framework2, admin

I am createing a cms based on zend framework 2 . I have som modules , let's say News module.
It has two controllers one for backend and one for front page :

```
News Module :
-- AdminController 
-- IndexController
```

My question is How can I list all AdminControllers in my admin module ?
I think it can be achieved by event manager but I don't know how

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Admin module does this:

- check a config key (i.e. `super_cms`)
- check if a subkey exists (i.e. `controllers`)
- foreach entries in said subkey, list them on your webpage

Your News module does this:

```
//module.config.php
return [
    'super_cms' => [
        'controllers' => [
            'NewsModule\Controller\AdminController' => [
                'label'      => 'News',
                'permission' => 'Admin',
                'route'      => 'news/admin'
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Now with this setup, you could do a `foreach` on the `controllers` and create a navigation that has all your controllers listed that you need. You could specify dedicated `label` options, you could assign `permission` keys that are required for access or you could assign a dedicated `route` to call.

This is all up to you tho. But without configuration, nothing works. There are "magic" ways, yes, but they would all require you to recursively scan lots and lots of directories which you don't want! Seriously, you don't!